# how to use librtmp in ffmpeg?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, rtmp

I have found a lib that can stream rtmp protocal using ffmpeg,and then I compiled ffmpeg with --enable-librtmp. But what will be next step? I can't find any example for using this feature?

Comment: i mean how to combine the librtmp and ffmpeg internal rtmp function to  communicate with the fms server?

Answer (score 4):

Now you can open rtmp URLs through the abstract ffmpeg interface:

```
AVFormatContext *s = NULL;
int ret = avformat_open_input(&s, "rtmp://server[:port][/app][/playpath][ keyword=value]...", NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: yes, avformat_open_input() has open a rtmp session with the server,is that correct? and i also want to use librtmp to send and received custom message ,how could use the same session with the ffmpeg one?

Comment: now i can stream rtmp protocol with the server using ffmpeg abstract interface,like 
    avformat_open_input.. 
and i also can use librtmp's method like 
    RTMP_Init(rtmpclient); RTMP_SetupURL(rtmpclient, kFMServerUrl);
to communicate with the server.
but i don't know how could i use the same session

Comment: You should not use rtmp lower-level functions directly. You need to work with the `AVFormatContext` through the standard ffmpeg API.

Comment: i am wondering could 'AVFormatContext' can decode the amf packet from the fms server? and how could i send message to the server through AVFormatContext?